# Multiple Cloud files on Parse Server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, parse-server

I'm hosting Parse Server open source project. I have all my cloud function in `cloud/main.js`. This file is getting a bit too big. How can I have multiple cloud files ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can export the other files as "modules" and then use require("..") to reference them from `main.js`. This [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/638) may help you.